# Division in Haskell

Tags: haskell, division

I'm making a function in Haskell that halves only the evens in a list and I am experiencing a problem. When I run the complier it complains that you can't perform division of an int and that I need a fractional int type declaration. I have tried changing the type declaration to float, but that just generated another error. I have included the function's code below and was hoping for any form of help.

```
halfEvens :: [Int] -> [Int]
halfEvens [] = []
halfEvens (x:xs) | odd x = halfEvens xs
                 | otherwise = x/2:halfEvens xs
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I think you want x `div` 2 in this case. I'll let someone else confirm that I'm right (not 100% sure I am) and give a more complete explanation.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use [`div`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:div), which performs integer division:

```
halfEvens :: [Int] -> [Int]
halfEvens [] = []
halfEvens (x:xs) | odd x = halfEvens xs
                 | otherwise = x `div` 2 : halfEvens xs
```

The [`(/)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-47-) function requires arguments whose type is in the class Fractional, and performs standard division.  The `div` function requires arguments whose type is in the class Integral, and performs integer division.

More precisely, `div` and `mod` round toward negative infinity.  Their cousins, `quot` and `rem`, behave like [integer division in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c) and round toward zero.  `div` and `mod` are usually correct when doing modular arithmetic (e.g. when calculating the day of the week given a date), while `quot` and `rem` are slightly faster (I think).

Playing around a bit in GHCi:

```
> :t div
div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
> :t (/)
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
> 3 / 5
0.6
> 3 `div` 5
0
> (-3) `div` 5
-1
> (-3) `quot` 5
0
> [x `mod` 3 | x <- [-10..10]]
[2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1]
> [x `rem` 3 | x <- [-10..10]]
[-1,0,-2,-1,0,-2,-1,0,-2,-1,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1]
```

Comment: Yes, quot is faster because that's what the machine instruction tends to do.  Except for the NS32k processor that had both kinds of division instructions.

Comment: Does ghc optimize division by a power of 2 into a right-shift?  An arithmetic right shift of n bits will divide by 2**n, but it will round towards negative infinity (if you right shift -1, you still get -1).  To round towards 0, you have to add (2**n)-1 if the input is negative before shifting.  In this case, `div` should be faster than `quot`

Comment: @pat, I doubt it.  ghc does not do very many arithmetic tricks.

Comment: @luqui: I wonder if the underlying compiler (GCC, LLVM, etc.) can do it, even after the operation is obfuscated by the code that implements `div` using `quot`.

Answer (score 1):

I should add that using `map` would simplify the code.

```
HalfIfEven n
  | even n = n `div` 2
  | otherwise = n

halfEvens = map halfIfEven
```

Comment: But that doesn't give you the same result. The original code removes the odds, yours does not. Simplest would probably be `halfEvens = map (\`div\` 2) . filter even`