# Divided number in prolog

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

How can using dividing between two numbers by using subtraction instead of (/). This is my code to calculate mod by using subtraction:

```
predicates
    div(integer,integer,integer)
clauses
    div(X,Y,Z):-X>Y,X1=X-1,div(X1,Y,Z),!.
    div(X,Y,Z):-X<y,X=Z,!.
    div(X,Y,Z):-X=Y,Z=0,!.
```

i solve it

```
predicates

div(integer,integer,integer).

clauses
div(1,_,0):-!.
div(0,_,0):-!.
div(X,Y,M):- X1=X-Y,div(X1,Y,M1),M=M1+1.
```

Comment: Are you wanting to do mod or division? Your question says division, but you're saying your example code is mod. Also, can out explain, in common language, what each of your predicate means and what each of your clauses means? I think it's unclear. But I think it has been basically solved here, even though nothing was marked as a "solution": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954314/divison-and-remainder-in-prolog

Comment: no,i want  Instead of using 4/2=2 i want use like this  4-2=2, 2-2=0.by using sub

Comment: can u help me please??

Comment: And for 11/4 you want 2? Look at the problem/answers I linked and see if that helps. It has the ideas that you need.

Comment: it is very difficult i want to send (4,2) the out put is 2 or(11,4)=2

Comment: You only need to use the `divit` predicate defined in the link I show but remove or ignore the remainder. Give it a try. :)

Comment: i cant please if u can help me because my exam tomorrow

Comment: You cannot assign an arithmetic expression with `=`, you need to use `is`. For example, `X1 is X - Y`. Good show on your solution; it is in the right direction! It works if the remainder of `X` divided by `Y` is `0` or `1` but it gives a stack overflow otherwise (e.g., try `div(10, 4, Q)`. You need a clause that just checks for `X < Y` and provides `X` as the quotient (just like the one you had in your first try).